# Help with product images generated in cache

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, media-images

I have added clear, higher resolution images in admin panel but don't know why the images looks a lot transparent in front end. 
URL: store.enconnex.com

[image: admin panel]

[image: product page]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some issue with CSS. Check if the image is getting unwanted opacity from some custom css or what. Or you can share the URL of the product page. Then I can tell you what exactly is it.

Comment: URL: https://store.enconnex.com/rf-shielded-cabinet-2.html